# Resize third party icon in wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel, icons

Is it possible to resize third party icons in wingpanel?

[image: big icon]

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of extra icons meant for third-party apps that you can use called elementaryPlus that fit well with the default elementary icon theme.

First you'll need to download [elementary tweaks](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks) (allows for customization of gtk themes and icons and more). Using command line:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

You can then download [elementaryPlus](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus) icon set with command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybre/elementaryplus
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementaryplus
```

Go to *System Settings > Tweaks > Appearance* and set *Icons* to the 'elementaryPlus' option.

I'm not completely sure if elementaryPlus has an icon that matches the application you are using, but it's worth a try. Perhaps you could also take a look at various other icon themes such as numix, paper, etc.